# VB.net alternative way of HttpWebRequest using POST method

Tags: vb.net, post, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

Here is my code using HttpWebRequest to automatically fill-up a web form and submits it.

```
            Dim cweb As String = "http://www.yellowpages.com/novato-ca/mip/creative-memories-consultant-senior-director-461725587/send_email?lid=171673036"
            Dim POST As String = "&email%5Bto_address%5D=recipient@email.com&email%5Bfrom_name%5D=Test Name&email%5Bfrom_address%5D=sender@mail.com&email%5Bnote%5D=Hello There"       

            Dim request As HttpWebRequest
            Dim response As HttpWebResponse

            request = CType(WebRequest.Create(cweb), HttpWebRequest)
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.72 Safari/537.36"
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = True
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            request.ContentLength = POST.Length
            request.Method = "POST"
            request.KeepAlive = True

            Dim requestStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
            Dim postBytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(POST)
            requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length)
            requestStream.Close()

            response = CType(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
            response.Close()
```

In this code I have used yellowpages' mailing form as an example. Yes it does let me fill-up and submit but I want another alternatives. Is there any other alternatives aside from WebClient as i have tried it already that is able to send POST requests? I have read about topics regarding System.Net.Sockets that it is able to send POST request, but I don't know where to start. Any tips will be gladly accepted. I really find HttpWebRequest and WebClient abit slow in sending POST requests.

Comment: As you haven't tried any other methods of doing this so far, I have to ask: you find `HttpWebRequest` and `WebClient` a bit slow compared to what?  You are correct that you can use sockets to send a HTTP POST.  You can use them to send almost anything network-related as they are the comms infrastructure underlying things like `HttpWebRequest`.  There's no guarantee that rolling your own HTTP classes will speed things up.

Comment: I wanted to know how to send HTTP POST using sockets but I don't know where to start. I find it confusing on how do I send POST requests by the use of sockets most examples I have read are offline based where the server and the client are in the same program only which I can't implement based on my HttpWebRequest code above.

Comment: I'm still lost as to why you seem to have a problem with `HttpWebRequest` and `WebClient`.  This is the purpose they're built for, and you're simply reinventing the wheel if you use .Net Sockets to essentially rewrite chunks of their functionality.  That said, a quick Google lead me to many answers to your query, a number of them right here on StackOverflow.  I'd suggest you do a little more research, then come back and ask specific questions about things you don't understand.  Start with Googling "how to send HTTP request using .Net sockets."  It worked for me.

Comment: I wanted to get rid of the delay, i have observed that HttpWebRequest and WebClient would wait for the server to respond before the request has been done which results into 1 - 3 seconds delay.

Comment: webclient.proxy = Nothing   will fix that delay

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can try to use this way

```
Using sendto As New Net.WebClient
    Dim param As New Specialized.NameValueCollection
    param.Add("param1", "value1")
    param.Add("param2", "value2")
    Dim response_bytes = sendto.UploadValues(yourUrl, "POST", param)
    Dim response_body = (New Text.UTF8Encoding).GetString(response_bytes)
End Using
```

Comment: "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send."